# Combining JavaScript generators and classes

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, generator, redux-saga

I want to instantiate a class that receives a generator in the constructor.

I cannot find any documentation on how to accomplish this.

In a broader sense, I'm using Redux-Saga and am trying to generalize async logic via classes.

```
class GeneratorClass {
    constructor(generator) {
        this.func = generator
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply pass in the generator's identifier to the constructor:

```js
class GeneratorClass {
  constructor(generator) {
    this.func = generator
  }
}

function* generator() {
  yield 1;
  yield 10;
}

myGenerator = new GeneratorClass(generator)

console.log(myGenerator.func().next())
```

You could also pass in parameters to the generator by using a wrapping function:

```js
class GeneratorClass {
  constructor(generator, start) {
    this.func = generator(start)
  }
}

function generator(i) {
  return function*() {
    yield i + 1;
    yield i + 10;
  }
}

myGenerator = new GeneratorClass(generator, 10)

console.log(myGenerator.func().next())
```